# How to update QProgressbar from another module?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, progress-bar, signals-slots

I want to update a progress bar in my main gui class from another module. Since the progress bar value has to be updated while the gui is still running in its main event loop, I created a thread for it. I am not able to update the progress value from the thread.

This is just bare bone code of what I actually want to do, but it produces the same error.

progress.py

```
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal


class ProgressUpdate(QObject):

progress_signal = pyqtSignal(int)

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.progress_update()

def progress_update(self):
    for i in range(0, 101):
        self.progress_signal.emit(i)
        sleep(0.01)
```

main.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QProgressBar, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
from progress import ProgressUpdate


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.progress_bar)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress')
        self.p_thread = ProgressThread()
        self.p_thread.start()
        self.show()

    def update_progress(self, val):
        self.progress_bar.setValue(val)


class ProgressThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.obj = ProgressUpdate()
        self.obj.progress_signal.connect(Example.update_progress)
    

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I'm running this, the progress bar shows up, but it stays at 0, it doesn't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate QObject and thread, it makes it more difficult to connect the signal and slot properly. The progress.py file can contain the QThread with the loop to emit the value every interval.

```
class ProgressThread(QtCore.QThread):

    progress_signal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(0, 101):
            self.progress_signal.emit(i)
            sleep(0.01)
```

And in main.py, connect the signal from the thread to the slot in the class.

```
class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.progress_bar)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress')
        self.p_thread = ProgressThread()
        self.p_thread.progress_signal.connect(self.update_progress)
        self.p_thread.start()
        self.show()

    def update_progress(self, val):
        self.progress_bar.setValue(val)

    
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```